# Bubble Sort Two Dimensional Array

Tags: ruby

I've been implementing an exercise on bubbling sorting.

So far, managed to bubble sort through an array.

Let's say, we have our `array = ([5,6,7], [2,3,4])`

How can I bubble sort through this without modifying the original array or using sort?

The exercise requires that I do not copy/duplicate/clone/edit or use a sort method.

My code to bubble sort through a regular array:

```
def bubble_sort(array)
is_sorted = false
  until is_sorted
    is_sorted = true
    (array.count - 1).times do |i|
      if array[i] > array[i + 1]
        array[i], array[i + 1] = array[i + 1], array[i]
        is_sorted = false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

arr

Comment: where is your code..? show us.. Or if you don't want to modify the original one, take a copy of the original one by using `#dup`/`#clone` method. On the dup object, start working..

Comment: `copy = array[0, array.length]` would be allowed or no? You will have to make a copy of the array *somehow* or it's not possible to do this...unless you return some kind of crazy wrapper method around the original array that uses an association table to reference values.

Comment: Are the sub-arrays sorted? Should they be in the result? FYI - bubble sort is all about changing the array _in place_. Doing that without modifying (or at least copying) the original array would make whatever you write _not a bubble sort_...

Comment: @UriAgassi I'm confused by the exercise due to the requirements. The final array should be: [2,3,4, 5,6,7]. The only hint provided is using indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual I learned quite a lot solving the OPs homework :-)

Firstly "do not copy/duplicate/clone/edit or use a sort method" just means that you have to implement your own algorithm.  It does **not** mean you shouldn't copy the array passed to your function.  You **must** copy your original array to avoid the side effect of modifying the original array.

However! if you simply copy the array `new_array = array` ruby will copy by reference.

That means that both variables will still point to the same data structure.  Your sort will happily sort the numbers and the array passed as a parameter will be modified.

To fix this you need to copy the array using the dup function.
`new_array = array.dup`

Then the bubble sort function ends up looking like this:

```
def bubble_sort(array)
  result = array.dup
  begin
    sorted = true
    (0..result.length - 2).each do |i|
      if result[i] > result[i + 1]
        result[i], result[i+1] = result[i+1], result[i]
        sorted = false
      end
    end
  end while !sorted
  result
end
```

Some test code:

```
a = [9,8,7,6,5,5,9,]
puts "array before sorting:"
puts a.inspect
puts "sorted array returned by function"
puts bubble_sort(a).inspect
puts "original array after sorting:"
puts a.inspect
```

Resulting output:

```
>ruby mysort.rb
array before sorting:
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 9]
sorted array returned by function
[5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
original array after sorting:
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array that is a copy of the original and sort that. That will let you keep the original array and have the sorted array.

Comment: The exercise requires that I do not copy/clone/edit or use a sort method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just combine the two arrays into a single array and then run a typical bubble sort?

```
def combine_arrays(arr1,arr2)
  final = arr1 + arr2
  sorted = true
  while sorted do
    sorted = false
    (0..final.length - 2).each do |x|
      if final[x] > final[x+1]
        final[x], final[x+1] = final[x+1], final[x]
        sorted = true
      end
    end
  end
  final
end

p combine_arrays([1,3,5],[2,4,6]) => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: this way the original array hasn't been modified or duplicated, simply creating a new array from the 2 originals?

Answer (score 0):

i think the simplest way for Bubble Sorting multi Dimensional Arrays is:

```
int main()
 {
    const size_t row = 4,col=6;
    int temp;
    int arr[row][col] = { { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }, { 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7 }, {18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13 }, { 24,23,22,21,20,1 } };
    for (auto &row : arr)
     {
      for (int i = 0; i != col; ++i)
       {
        int flag = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j != col-i - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (row[j]>row[j+1])
            {
                temp = row[j];
                row[j] = row[j + 1];
                row[j + 1] = temp;
                flag = 1;

            }
        }
        if (!flag)break;
      }
 }

for (auto &row : arr)
{
    for (auto col : row)
        cout << col << " ";
    cout << endl;
}


return 0;
```

}